# Debian x64 and Nvidia optimus drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an ASUS laptop. It has a Core i5 CPU with integrated graphics and a discrete NVIDIA 310M GPU.

I have Windows 7 installed and I'm sure that everything is working. Today I installed Debian 7.1. I'm using GNOME GUI and Xorg.

I installed the Nvidia drivers following this guide: [Click!](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/install-nvidia-proprietary-unix-driver/)

I thought everything went OK, because I had no errors during the guide. After second reboot I was stucked at black blank screen with blinking cursor. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> I figured out that I got "No devices detected." error with the following error log (excerpted from [here](http://pastebin.com/3UHNE6UD)):

```
[    79.779] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    79.779] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    79.779] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    79.779]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    79.779]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    79.779] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.59  Wed Jun  6 21:21:24 PDT 2012
[    79.779] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    79.779] (--) using VT number 8

[    79.783] (EE) No devices detected.
[    79.783]
Fatal server error:
[    79.783] no screens found
```

So I was trying to google the answer and I figured out that I should add

```
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
```

to the "Device" section in xorg.conf file. After I added this line I rebooted and I got again black screen, but without blinking cursor this time. It's too long to post, so it's hosted [here](http://pastebin.com/hsLXeTxC).

I couldn't find a error, but still nothing happens.

I figured out that if I remove xorg.conf file, the system boots but Xorg is not turned on.

[This](http://pastebin.com/BYFvmCmV) is my config file.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have a asus laptop with i5 and nvidia gt 630M graphics.

This is what I did for installing drivers:

Installed nvidia drivers from the official debian [site](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22). The link that you have specified is a third party link. I would recommend you to follow the official debian guides that are available on the wiki.

Next I added the "contrib" and "non-free" repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

added the following lines at the end.

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Good till now.Then I installed the linux headers and kernel modules for nvidia graphics drivers using the command :

```
apt-get install build-essential pkg-config help2man libx11-dev libbsd-dev libglib2.0-dev
```

Good, I had the nvidia drivers installed on my system.

And everything worked fine for me. However since my gpu supported optimus technology, I had to install bumbelbee. Depends on whether your nvidia gpu has optimus support or not.

Hope it helps. All the best!